# wordpress next and previous post link?

Tags: wordpress, paging

i want add **next post** and **previous post** link my each post. i already do it. but i want when  last post that time **next post** link will hide and first post time **previous post** will be hide

bellow my code is working ...

```
 <?php
     $prev_post = get_previous_post();
     if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?>" class="prev-post">
      <span class="left_arrow"></span> <?php _e("Previous Post", "twentytwelve"); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?>" class="next-post">
    <?php _e("Next Post", "twentytwelve"); ?>&nbsp; <span class="right_arrow"></span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

bellow one suppose to work to but not.

```
<?php if($show_prevnext_post == 1) { ?>

    <?php
     $prev_post = get_previous_post();
     if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?>" class="prev-post">
      <span class="left_arrow"></span> <?php _e("Previous Post", "twentytwelve"); ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>" title="<?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?>" class="next-post">
    <?php _e("Next Post", "twentytwelve"); ?>&nbsp; <span class="right_arrow"></span></a>
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php } ?>
```

i don't understan why this is not working. should i need to anything in function.php

Comment: is $show_prevnext_post returing value 1

Comment: if i use <?php if($show_prevnext_post == 1) { ?> .. then my next previous even not coming.

Comment: from where you getting the value for $show_prevnext_post and what value you passing..

Comment: it was copied from another theme. i just see that have function in another page. and not so easy to use i guess.. but same what i wanted. i can able at last make it.. just simpley useing  @sarahm link. ....

Comment: thats good you able to solve but you should know what you are doing before asking others..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at WordPress's [previous_post_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)() and [next_post_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link)() functions. They will only output a link if there's a prev/next post. But it will only work if you use them in the WordPress Post Loop

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: thanks you so much. yea finally i can able to make . your link help me. thanks again @sarahm...

Comment: is there anyway to add title="<?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?>.. this code previous and next link. that title for show next/previous post title.

Comment: @santanukumar ... actually i am new wordpress and also php knowladge very poor.

the theme from i copied. there have two more file for that function 

one file like that `global $data; //fetch options stored in $data -->

global $show_prevnext_post, $show_author_box, $show_related_posts ;

$show_prevnext_post = $data['show_prevnext_post']; 

 `

Comment: another file like this 

`$of_options[] = array( "name" => __("Show Previous & Next Post", "themename"),
     "desc" => __("Here you can show Previous & Next Post or not in single post page", "themename"),
     "id" => "show_prevnext_post",
     "std" => 1,
     "type" => "checkbox");
`
so do you think i can make that like normally in function page. i tried but no work... but this is good also caz it's show next and previous post title also.